# Was genau haben "das Trum", "das Trumm" und "die Trümmer" miteinander zu tun?

Tags: etymology

Die drei Wörter im Titel scheinen auf eine gemeinsame Wurzel zurückzugehen:

- **die Trümmer** - Pluralwort für Reste von irgendwas nach einer Zerstörung
- **das Trumm** - Regionales/umgangssprachliches Wort für "ein Mordsding" von Ausmaß oder Gewicht, Plural: *Trümmer*
- **das Trum** - fachsprachliche Bezeichnung für eine Hälfte eines Kettenantriebs, z.B. beim Motorrad, Plural: *Trume* oder *Trümer*

Ich würde gerne wissen, ob meine obige Annahme stimmt, und wo die gemeinsame Herkunft liegt.

Comment: _"die ich für richtig und hinreichend halte"_ Was fehlt denn noch bei meiner letzten? Was **das Trum** betrifft, habe ich nach kurzem googlen schon arge Zweifel ob die Wörter einen gemeinsamen Stamm haben. Trotzdem mal ein Upvote, ich finde die Frage an sich schon interessant.

Comment: BTW als Plural für _Trum_ scheint auch _Trümmer_ gebräuchlich.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Das dachte ich auch. Da dachte iach auch noch, "Trum" und "Trumm" wäre dasselbe. Nach Nachschau im Wörterbuch denke ich es nicht mehr.

Comment: Gilt „show your effort“ nur für Anfänger und Neulinge?

Comment: @CarstenS Als was wertest du "Nach Nachschau im Wörterbuch"? Zugegebenermaßen habe ich diese Frage gestellt, weil ich sie spannend und fürs Publikum interessant fand. Nicht, weil ich keine Antwort darauf gefunden hätte. Wenn das kein legitimer Fragegrund ist, lösche ich die Frage gerne wieder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Deutsche Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm [bestätigt in seinen Erläuterungen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT13414#XGT13414) die Annahme, dass alle drei Wörter auf eine gemeinsame Wurzel zurückgehen.

Der Eintrag für "Trum" verweist schlicht auf die Erläuterungen zu "Trumm".

Der Eintrag "**Trumm**" wiederum nennt "**Trum**" als gleichbedeutend und weist "**Trümmer**" als Plural der beiden Worte aus. Im Weiteren wird dann niederhochdeutsch als Ursprung von "Trumm (Trum)" genannt.

Die Bedeutung des "**Trum**" ist ursprünglich "Stock, Baumstamm, abgehauener Holzklotz". Im Mittelhochdeutschen ist die Verwendung in dieser Bedeutung allgemein gebräuchlich, hält sich aber beim Übergang zum Neuhochdeutschen nur in einigen Sonderbedeutungen.

Eine dieser Sonderbedeutungen ist "Ende eines Seils, Faden" o. ä., insbesondere auch beim Weben. Das scheint die Herkunft der Bedeutung im Maschinenbau zu sein, wo ein Trum ein freier, nicht aufliegender Abschnitt eines Riemens, einer Kette oder eines Seils ist.

(Andere Sonderbedeutungen gibt es insbesondere noch im Bergbau.)

Der Plural "**Trümmer**" hingegen hat seit dem 18. Jahrhundert eine gesonderte Entwicklung genommen. Dabei bürgerte sich die Bedeutung als "Reste bedeutend erscheinender Dinge, großer Bauwerke, riesiger Naturschöpfungen" usw. ein, also die, die heute allgemein bekannt ist.

Answer (score 1):

Trum ist Laut Duden ein „Nebenform von Trumm“. Und Trümmer ist laut Duden der Plural von „Trumm“. Die Herkunft von Trumm wiederum ist:

> mittelhochdeutsch, althochdeutsch drum = Endstück, Splitter, Herkunft ungeklärt

Die drei Wörter sind also eigentlich nur Formen von „Trumm“ und haben also alle den gleichen Ursprung.

Comment: "Endstück, Splitter" erklärt für mich "Trum" (ein bißchen) und "Trümmer"  (ziemlich) - Aber irgendwie jetzt ganz und gar nicht "Trumm".

Answer (score 1):

Die Etymologie auf [dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Trumm) gibt hier Aufschluss:

> Trümmer Plur. ‘Ruinen, Reste, Bruchstücke eines einstmals Ganzen’, verselbständigter Plural von obd. und rhein. Trumm n. m. ‘großer, schwerer Brocken’, ahd. thrum (8. Jh.), mhd. drum, trum, frühnhd. trum ‘Endstück, Ende, Stück, Splitter’

Dass das heutige Wort Trum hier einen Bezug haben soll, konnte ich so nicht bestätigt finden und es ergibt von der Wortbedeutung her für mich auch keinen Sinn, hier einem Zusammenhang zu Trumm/Trümmer zu suchen.